# Query by post type or category

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, themes

I now that WP_Query can query by post_type and category but i need to get data from custom post type or from category which is standard post type. Adding category to my custom post type is not an option. Any suggestion how to aproach this?

Comment: [Here's a really good link](https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628) to all the available args available for WP Query.

Comment: Problem is that I have to get from custom post type (everything) and normal posts from category. Standard query will get my post which ar in custom post type and in this particular catergory.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution

```
    $posts = array_merge($posts1, $posts2);
    function cmp($a, $b) {
         return strcmp($a->post_title, $b->post_title);
    }
    usort($posts, 'cmp');
```